# Wordpress search box to search only videos on my website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page called "Product Training" and on this page there are informative videos on the products. This list is growing. I would like to have a search box at the top of the page that will only search through these videos and not the whole website. How do I direct this search box to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `functions.php` and I hope these video MIME would suffice.

```
$video_mimes  = array( 'video/mp4', 'video/x-flv', 'application/x-mpegURL', 'video/MP2T', 'video/3gpp', 'video/quicktime', 'video/x-msvideo','video/x-ms-wmv' );

function custom_search_filter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_mime_type', $video_mimes);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','custom_search_filter');
```